# How to solve the problem which is a sum of convex and nonconvex functions?

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization

I attempt to solve an optimization which is a sum of two convex functions and one non-convex function described as follows:

$$g(x,y) = a{\log_2}{\left( {1 + x} \right)} + b\log_2 \left[ 1 + c(x - dy) \right] - x(y+e)$$

The two logarithm terms are convex (can prove the convexity using hessian matrix) while the third term in the function $g(x,y)$ is non-convex. 
Could anyone give me a suggestion to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are the logarithms convex? Are $a$ and $b$ negative?

Comment: Are you trying to minimize or maximize $g$?

Comment: hi, I am trying to maximum the function $g$, and $a, b$ are both positive. It makes the two logarithms are concave.

Comment: Maximizing a concave function is the "mirror" of minimizing a convex one. The problem is $xy$. If the logarithms are concave, please explain the first phrase in your question.

Comment: Yes. I mean "Is there solution to solve the maximization problem of the function $g$ when it is a sum of convex functions and a non-convex function". I am trying to address the product $xy$ by linearizing it:
Denote $u = (x+y)/2, v = (x-y)/2$, then the third term becomes quadratic functions. So the function $g$ might can be solved w.r.t. $(u, v)$

Comment: I still don't understand. You have two concave functions.